# how to upload multiple files, store their paths in different columns in a row PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli

First time that i made an image upload in my site everything worked fine.
but now i created 2 more images columns in my row...
in my DB i have these 3 columns...
|image|img_v1|img_v2|

When i upload my imgs only the first works, and i know why only that one works.
The problem is that im not doing it right, so i can upload the other imgs...
here is my code...

```
      $error = ''; 
      if(isset($_POST['submit_post'])){
      $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
      $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
      if($_FILES['image']['name'] !=''){
      $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $image_ext = pathinfo($image_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $image_path = '../clientes/img/'.$image_name;
      $image_db_path = 'img/'.$image_name;

      $target1 = 'img/';$target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['img_v1']['name']); 
      $target2 = 'img/';$target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['img_v2']['name']);
     ////this above send's the name from the img to the server ex...img/05.jpg

      if($image_size < 10000000){
      if($image_ext == 'jpg' || $image_ext == 'png' || $image_ext == 'jpeg' || $image_ext == 'gif'){
                                  if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_path)){

   $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (title, description, image, img_v1, img_v2, category, status) VALUES ('$title', '$_POST[description]', 
'$image_db_path', '$target1', '$target2', '$_POST[category]', '$_POST[status]')";....
```

so my image is uploading cuz its set the path here...

```
 $image_path = '../clientes/img/'.$image_name;
```

i have to set $target1 and $target2 image path so it can upload.

i've tried this...`if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_path,$target1,$target2))`
but of sure it didnt work cuz i only works with 2 parameters.

my input field are...

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="images">Centralizada</label>
      <input id="images" type="file" name="image" class="btn btn-danger">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="img_v1">V1</label>
      <input id="img_v1" type="file" name="img_v1" class="btn btn-danger">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="img_v2">V2</label>
      <input id="img_v2" type="file" name="img_v2" class="btn btn-danger">
      </div>
```

I'm very noob at php cuz i'm still learning.
So what i have to do to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

You can upload your three images separately and then set path to be stored in db in some variable and then at the end you can save it in db by insert query.

```
$tmp_name1 = Your_first_image;
$tmp_name2 = Your_Second_image;
$tmp_name3 = Your_Third_image;
$uploads_dir = Your_destination_for_image;

$uploads_dir1 = $uploads_dir.'/'.$tmp_name1;
$uploads_dir2 = $uploads_dir.'/'.$tmp_name2;
$uploads_dir3 = $uploads_dir.'/'.$tmp_name3;
$db_image1 = '';
$db_image2 = '';
$db_image3 = '';

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name1, $uploads_dir1))
{
    $db_image1 = $uploads_dir1;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name2, $uploads_dir2))
{
    $db_image2 = $uploads_dir2;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name3, $uploads_dir3))
{
    $db_image3 = $uploads_dir3;
}

$ins_sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (title, description, image, img_v1, img_v2, category, status) VALUES ('$title', '$_POST[description]', 
'$db_image1', '$db_image2', '$db_image3', '$_POST[category]', '$_POST[status]')
```

Comment: explanation is on top, its mentioned to upload three images separately and then set values in variables. isnt that readable?

Comment: but its neither complex nor incorrect. This method is also valid.

Comment: developer has clearly mentioned that he have different input fields, and my solution is according to the question asked. you should read question and answer both before doing downvote and adding your comments.

Comment: @JamesAllan sorry your answer is not clear to me, can you please clarify?

Comment: the link i sent you can edit the code,where its wrong

Comment: @EktaPuri i will clarify

Comment: iin my database i have 3 columns in a row that are images...these rows names are...| image | img_v1 | img_v2 |...and im trying to make a multiple file upload. so i can upload 3 images at the same time in there three rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121010/discussion-between-ekta-puri-and-james-allan).

Comment: in each img row it holds the db path like this... /img/pic.jpg....and i store all the imgs uploades in a file inside of ../clients/img